# a numerical headline

Tags: cipher

I picked up the English-language version of the popular tabloid *Bild von Affen*, and was surprised to see this headline. What does it mean?

> 1 69 39 64 13 71, 　 46 27 6 12 61 33 　 7 74 32 24 44 47 　 25 36 　 15 62 35 43

Hint:

> I couldn't figure it out, so I texted a friend of mine who works at the newspaper.
>
> Me: What's that headline this morning, with all the numbers?
> My friend: What about it?
> Me: Well, where do all the numbers come from?
> My friend: They were generated randomly.
> Me: You mean to tell me those numbers were picked at random?
>
> And I got back confirmation. I'm more confused than before.

Another hint (which will make sense only if you've read the first):

> The confirmation I got back was pretty emphatic. It indicated that I was precisely correct.

Another hint:

> Still at a loss, I texted another friend of mine, someone who's good at puzzles of this sort.
>
> Me: Did you see the numerical headline in the *Bild*?
> My friend: Yeah, have you figured out what it means?
> Me: No, I've been racking my brain all day.
> My friend: I'm driving my mother to the church tonight. Come along with us; maybe you'll get some inspiration.

Another hint (which will make sense if you've read the preceding one):

> The trip to church didn't enlighten me (though I certainly had fun). On the way back, I admitted as much to my friend, who told me to check what the highest-valued number is in the headline. So I checked, and it's 74, but I'm still lost.

Comment: It looks to me like there's five words, separated by 3 spaces, and each letter is separated by 1 space. I also noticed that no number ever repeats, so maybe the cipher involves some sort of math done for each letter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been thinking about this one for a while with no progress, and then today, finally... bingo! The headline reads:

> **BONOBO, GIBBON BONING IN BONN**

This, of course, is a relevant headline for a German-language tabloid newspaper called *Bild von Affen*, because:

> (i) it's clearly a sensational story (hence its appearance in the tabloid press);
>  (ii) 'Affen' is German for 'apes' (of which bonobo and gibbon are two types);
>  (iii) Bonn is a city in Germany.
>
>  The use of 'Bild' is a reference to the *real* [German tabloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bild) of that name.

How to crack this? In truth, I probably would not have lit upon the subject matter without the hints, but armed with those I was at last able to work out that this cipher revolved around...

> **BINGO**, the popular game of chance usually played in large groups, involving the random drawing of numbered balls by a 'caller', with the aim of marking off the numbers arranged on your card before other players do theirs, in order to win a prize. Specifically, this cipher relies on what is commonly considered the *[American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(American_version))* version, which uses the numbers 1-75 and a card that looks something like this:
>
>  [image: Example bingo card]
>  *<sup>Source: winkbingo.com</sup>*
>
>  The letters of 'BINGO' are written across the tops of the columns (one to each), the first of which contains 5 numbers randomly selected from the range 1-15, the second from 16-30, the third 31-45 (with one free space), the fourth 46-60, and the fifth 61-75.
>
>  To decrypt the cipher used here, we must work out in which bingo card column a number in the ciphertext would fall, and then replace it with the corresponding letter of 'BINGO' (so the output will comprise only the letters B, I, N, G, and O - it's fairly limited in its applications!).
>
>  As an example, the first word of our ciphertext comprises the six numbers `1 69 39 64 13 71` - both 1 and 13 appear in the 'B' column (1-15), 39 appears in the 'N' column (31-45), and all of 69, 64 and 71 appear in the 'O' column (61-75), giving us the output `BONOBO`. Repeating this process for the remaining numbers yields the full message: `BONOBO, GIBBON BONING IN BONN`.

How did the hints help?

> Hint 1: The numbers are *generated randomly*, like in a game of bingo!
>  Hint 2: To confirm emphatically that someone has hit upon the right understanding, you might choose to say "Bingo!"
>  Hint 3: It is common for many bingo games to take place in *church halls* and in the evening.
>  Hint 4: The narrator *had fun* at the church (it was a social function), and the largest number seen is 74 - there are 75 balls in an American-style bingo game.
>
>  Also worth noting is that no number appears twice in the ciphertext (as the question now stands after an earlier edit), just like how in a real bingo game no number can be drawn more than once...